# Coordinates on clickevent

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm new to @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet and Angular in general, so this is maybe just a newbie-issue...

I have an Angular.io (v5) project using the [@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-ngcli](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-ngcli)

Now I would like to get the coordinates of the point I clicked on the map. According to [Issue #51 get coordinates on click?](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/issues/51), I added this:

```
map.on('click', () => { console.log(e.latlng); });
```

to:

```
onMapReady(map: Map) {
    map.fitBounds(this.route.getBounds(), {
        padding: point(24, 24),
        maxZoom: 12,
        animate: true
    });
    map.on('click', () => { console.log(e.latlng); });
}
```

that gives me a runtime error:
`Cannot find name 'e'.`

Which kind of makes sense to me. So, I changed the code to:

`map.on('click', (e) => { console.log(e.latlng); });`

But this gives me an error too: `Property 'latlng' does not exist on type 'LeafletEvent'`

When I just put e to the console `console.log(e)` I can see the latlng-Property exists...
Why can't I access the coordinates with `e.latlng`?

My project is using:

*"@angular/cli": "1.4.7",*
*"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^2.5.1",*
*"@types/leaflet": "^1.2.0",*
*"leaflet": "^1.2.0",*

Comment: Can you try to get e.latlng.lat and e.latlng.lng?

Comment: @Pterrat: Yes. Then this Error pops up: `Property 'latlng' does not exist on type 'LeafletEvent'`

Comment: Is that a compiler error or a runtime error? In other words, do you see the error in the console or the browser?

Comment: @reblace It's a compiler error. I see it in the console e.g. when I use `ng build`

Comment: @CaptainInler That suggests that the issue is that the inferred type of ```e``` is the ```LeafletEvent```, which doesn't have the ```latlng``` property. So, the compiler is complaining. At runtime, the property is there because the concrete class is ```LeafletMouseEvent```, which does have ```latlng```. Like the two current answers suggest, you should try type checking and casting the event to ```LeafletMouseEvent``` and it should work. You can also cast like this: ```(e as LeafletMouseEvent).latlng```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is inferring that the event type is [LeafletEvent](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/leaflet--leaflet/interfaces/l.leafletevent.html), which doesn't have the latlng property. That's why you're getting this error.

The Leaflet docs indicate that this event is actually of type [LeafletMouseEvent](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/leaflet--leaflet/interfaces/l.leafletmouseevent.html), which extends LeafletEvent. So, you can cast the event to gain access to the properties of LeafletMouseEvent (as demonstrated below:

```
map.on('click', (<LeafletMouseEvent>e) => {
    console.log(e.latlng);
});
```

Comment: Your Code works, when I change it to: `map.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent>(e) => { console.log(e.latlng.lat); console.log(e.latlng.lng); });`

Comment: Do you mean: `map.on('click', (e) => { console.log(e.type); });`? This returns: `click`

Comment: Ok thank you, could you open an issue on github about this? It's not normal that e.type is click and e is a LeafletMouse object

Answer (score 8):

Try to "cast" it as a [`LeafletMouseEvent`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ddbf07cb69182b71500a31edd43937e42e1e5b51/types/leaflet/index.d.ts#L1166-L1171):

```ts
map.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent>(e) => { console.log(e.latlng) });
```

Comment: Casting works. But I had to change your code a bit to: `map.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent>(e) => { console.log(e.latlng); });`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Please do not forget to mark the answer that helped you solve your issue as _accepted_. This way people know that your problem is fixed. Once you have enough _reputation_, you will also be able to _upvote_.

Answer (score 0):

To have the `latlng` property, use parameter type `LeafletMouseEvent` instead of `LeafletEvent`.